# Why does the attribute 'name' of the sqlalchemy.Column instance disappear?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm writing the history of attribute changes for `sqlalchemy` models. Attributes list, which are important for history, I keep in the class attribute history_attributes.

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, Column, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
class HistoryAttribute:
    def __init__(self, descriptor, display_name, use_message=False):
        self.name = descriptor.name
        self.display_name = display_name
        self.use_message = use_message
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String(100))
    email = Column(String(100))
    history_attributes = (
        HistoryAttribute(descriptor=first_name, display_name='User name'),
        email
    )

print(User.history_attributes[0].name)
>>> None
print(User.history_attributes[1].name)
>>> email
```

Why does the attribute `"name"` of the `Column` instance disappear, if I pass one to constructor of other class? Of course, I can write `first_name = Column('first_name', String(100)` and code will work fine,
but I don't want to add `Column.name` explicitly. I avoided the problem using namedtuple, which I then pass to the constructor of the `HistoryAttribute` class, but it's very similar to a crutch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that the `name` attribute disappears, but that it hasn't been initialized yet. Look at the value of `first_name` as passed to `HistoryAttribute`: `Column(String(100))`; it does not contain any mention of the string `first_name`. SQLAlchemy will fill the name in later after the class is defined.

Answer (score 1):

As has been discussed, the issue is that `first_name.name` is set while the class is being constructed.
SQLAlchemy does have a mechanism for deferring an attribute definition until configuration time.  Try something like
    class User(Base):
        # ...
        @sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api.declared_attr
        def history_attributes(self):
            return (HistoryAttribute(self.first_name #...))

That will defer the construction of history_attributes until a point where column names are populated

Comment: declared_attr is not suitable, because I want to get history_attributes from class, but this gave rise to the idea of using the classmethod, which returns desired tuple with HistoryAttribute instances

Comment: I'm confused how declared_attr gets in the way.  After configuration, I'm fairly sure that accessing the class will give you the instances.  That is, during class construction, I am fairly sure the metaclass will replace the declared_attr with the right thing.  In your case classmethod will work, but unless you memoize it will be a bit shorter.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand you, but declared_attr gives me the same result (


[code example](https://codeshare.io/5RB0dB)

Comment: That's surprising.  That's not what I'm seeing in a somewhat similar but not identical situation